# best way to load multiple layouts in different .js files titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I need to laoad multiple layouts that are in diferent .js files. so whate I do in my current .js file is creating a new window like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url : 'NewJS.js'
});
win.open();
});
```

and in the new .js file I create a view and put all mi layout in that view. then i show my view with:

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(view);
```

The problem is that I get out of memory errors in Android and a believe it is because of the amount of window that I'm opening.

Is there a way to have one window and open a new layout from a different .js file in a button click for example?

I'm not using the alloy folder.